# What semantic notions connect "to turn, turn around, roll," to "bowed, arched"?

Tags: etymology

> [ [Etymonline :](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vault&allowed_in_frame=0)  ]  vault (n.1)
>   [...] Latin *volutus* "bowed, arched," past participle of
>   *volvere* "to turn, turn around, roll,"
>   from PIE root [*wel-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=*wel-&allowed_in_frame=0) (3) "to turn, revolve." [...]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on your question? Are you asking how *volutus* can come from *volvere*, given the meanings listed at Etymonline?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The latter: yes. The former: I accepted the helpful answer below, but please feel free to change my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you turn or (re)volve around something, you move along a curve, like the pencil of a pair of compasses (the pin is the centre). The path traversed could be a full circle, or part of a circle, or a less regular curve. This curve is the result of the action of revolving, and as such it can be expressed by a passive form of the verb, the participium perfecti passivi *volutus*. This describes a curved appearance. A bow and an arch have curved shapes.